# How to set trasmit freq. on Baofeng UV5R to 0MHz manually

Tags: baofeng, transmitter

On this quesiton: [How can I avoid accidentally transmitting with a Baofeng UV-5R?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/how-can-i-avoid-accidentally-transmitting-with-a-baofeng-uv-5r) I learned how one can avoid accidentally transmitting on a Baofeng UV5R. This can be done using software by setting the trasmit frequency to 0 MHz.

My next question is: How can this be done manually?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question.   I hadn't considered this before since I am licensed for all the channels I have programmed into my radio.  But this would be great if I had an unlicensed helper who needed to be able to hear me and for whatever reason didn't want to use a cellphone.     I see the answer below and would only add that  CHIRP should be able to do it all for you.  No need to do anything at the keyboard except enable CHIRP communications.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done manually. The UV-5R does not a allow you to type in channel frequencies outside of the range it is set to.
So when you program a channel by going into frequency mode - type in the receive frequency 146910 for 146.910 and go to menu item 27 select the memory number you want to save 000 through 127 hit menu again to save the receiving freq. Exit the menu type in or scroll to the transmit frequency. This is where you cannot go beyond the range set for your UV-5R. This range can be changed in software but not through the radio interface. If you type in a number that is outside the range it will just cancel and go back to the number you were on. If you are at the lowest number in the range and hit the down arrow it will wrap up to the highest number in the range.